# boolean value not changing back to NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have it setup in the view for users to unsubscribe from notifications. They can successfully unsubscribe with the current code, but they cannot resubscribe however. The boolean value once changed to `1` will not revet back to `NULL`

```
<% if @user.no_email == true %>


<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
           <div class="forms">
                       <%= f.check_box :no_email, :value => nil %>
                       <%= f.submit 'Unsubscribe from all email notifications' %>
               </div>
       <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.no_email.nil? %>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
           <div class="forms">
                       <%= f.check_box :no_email, :value => 1 %>
                       <%= f.submit 'Subscribe to email notifications' %>
               </div>
       <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify matters:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div class="forms">
<%= f.check_box :no_email, :value => @user.no_email %>
<%= f.submit @user.no_email ? 'Unsubscribe' : 'Subscribe' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This will change values from false to true.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `== true` and `.nil?` to test boolean values. If the values is `false`, that `.nil?` check will fail. Just do something like:

```
if @user.no_email
```

and

```
if !@user.no_email
```